# Ctrl Right and Ctrl Left doesn't move from a word to another in Fish Shell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fish

When I use on Linux Mint my Fish Shell, using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> keys isn't moving the cursor to the previous or next word. It switches between an I and an N instead:

[image: Here is the I and then the N]

I cannot do partial completion then, so it's really annoying.

How can I fix this?

Output of bind | grep backward-word
[image: bind | grep backward-word]

Comment: Hi there, I have this on fish shell. When I go on bash it works properly.

Answer (score 4):

Your key binding configuration seems to be missing entries for
`\e[1;5C` and `\e[1;5D` which are the sequences of characters typically sent upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> in many `xterm`-like terminal emulators.

You can add those in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
bind \e\[1\;5C forward-word
bind \e\[1\;5D backward-word
```

That has been in `fish`'s default key binding since 2.0 ([this commit](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/164144f1265b26446eafa16091e0eed9e2344a9d) in 2010), you may want to upgrade.

Comment: Okay it kind of works but and I've got a fish 2.5... that's why I don't really get the problem... There is maybe some interference...
Usually I could navigate trough pre completion but yet it's not the case... Thanks a lot..

Comment: @Marc, is it possible that you've overridden the key binding configuration somehow in `~/.config/fish`? `grep -r bind ~/.config/fish`

Comment: @marc, Do those lines show-up in `/usr/share/fish/functions/fish_default_key_bindings.fish`?

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments. So yes these lines are in /usr/share/fish/functions/fish_default_key_bindings.fish:

    bind $argv \e\[1\;5C forward-word
    bind $argv \e\[1\;5D backward-word

Comment: @Marc, but get overridden somehow. Somewhere in `~/.config/fish`? Try running `strace -fo log -e open fish`. And look in the `log` for files that `fish` opens and if any of them contain key binding instructions.

Comment: Okay and it cannot be something done by Oh my fish?

Comment: I found that line in my fishd. file: SET fish_key_bindings:fish_vi_key_bindings

Comment: This solved my issue: set -U fish_key_bindings fish_default_key_bindings

Answer (score 1):

In fact it was the key bindings that where set to vi.

This command solved my issue: `set -U fish_key_bindings fish_default_key_bindings`